# Launching an iOS app on device reboot

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I want to write an iOS sample application which can launch itself whenever device is rebooted. Please share your thoughts and any pointers will be really helpful.

Setting VOIP in background modes seems to be one option.

**I am NOT looking for a Jail break solution.**

Comment: Unless you are working on jailbroken devices thats not possible.

Comment: Then you are out of luck. Apple does not allow apps to launch themselves. Only the user can launch an app on an iOS device. Period.

Answer (score 5):

There is a way if you have access to [MDM tools](https://www.apple.com/iphone/business/it/management.html) or the [Apple Configurator](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/apple-configurator/id434433123?mt=12), and are able to control the device and its' profile. For example, if you are the curator at a museum or you or a teacher and hand out iPads to students, you'll most certainly have this level of control; and since you're writing a sample application, I suppose this level of control is possible as well.

There is a feature known as **Single App Mode** ([see page 17](https://ssl.apple.com/uk/education/docs/ios_6_education_deployment_guide.pdf)) that locks a device into a single app. According to the documentation, if the device is powered down, the specified app will launch at boot. (I don't have the setup to confirm this.)

Note that Single App Mode is *not* the same as guided access mode, though people do tend to get them confused.

So should you have access to the right tools your original intent *may* be possible.

Comment: This sounds promising. I shall read the shared stuff and check if this suits me. Upvoting!

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, this is not possible. Your app does not have access to this level of system information.

What you could do is periodically send push-notifications with a payload that temporary allows you to access app functionality.

Comment: So when you say Push Notification, I assume you are talking about Apple Push Notification. Now, If my application is killed by iOS then can I still wake my app with Apple Push Notification?

Comment: @Abhinav No you can't.

Comment: @user2509601 That's not 100% true. It won't wake up the app completely, but it will launch certain delegate methods within the AppDelegate that can perform really minor, quick operations, like pinging a web service. Look into the UIBackgroundModes remote-notification system property.

Answer (score 1):

There is really not much you can do to achieve such functionality. The most you can do is to provide background fetching to prepare your app for when user launches it explicitly.

I have never seen a single app that could launch itself for no reason.

Hope this can be useful.

Answer (score 1):

Can't be done unless the device is jailbroken, and I can't help you with that.

Comment: Thanks you. I have updated my question to include that I am not looking for a jail break solution.